# How to post data to mongodb with dynamically generated fields using Angular js & Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am developing product upload page.
Few fields are fixed & few fields will be generated based on user selection, and then entire data will be posted to mongoDb.

**Model**

```
var productsSchema = new Schema({
    merchantId: {type: String, required: true},
    productName: {type: String, required: true},
    productDescription: {type: String, required: true},

    productStock: [
        {

            price: {type: Number, required: true},
            color: {type: String, required: true},

        }
    ],

    offerFromMerchant: {
        offerStartDate: {type: Date, required: false},
        offerEndDate: {type: Date, required: false},
        discountPercent: {type: Number, required: false}
    }
});
```

**Dynamically field generator controller method-Angular js**

```
$scope.choices = [];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({});
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    if(lastItem > 0){
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    }
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-12">
        <form ng-submit="addProducts()">
       <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <hr>
         <h3>Attributes</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productStock.price" placeholder="Enter price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Color</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productStock.color" placeholder="Enter color">
                            </div>
    </fieldset>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
                 </form>
              <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>  
        </div>  
</form><br/>
```

**POST method-Angular js**

```
$scope.addProducts = function () {

        $http.post('/products/createProduct', $scope.product).then(function (res) {
            console.log($scope.product);

        });
    }
```

I am trying to POST data with multiple attributes, but in database only single entry is present .

- So the problem is, I don't know how to send $scope.choices with $scope.product, because some of the fields will be binding to $scope.product, and attributes field will be binding to $scope.choices.So how can I Post this kind of data to web-service ?

Please help..

Comment: POST How? There is no code here showing a POST request or the request handler on the express side that would be actually talking to the database.

Comment: @NeilLunn : I have added Post method.I am posting data using web-service.

Comment: Seems like the "web-service" is the problem then. Post the code. But you also might take a look at the fact that you are modifying `$scope.choices` and you are sending `$scope.product`. So there's either more missing code here or you are simply modifying the wrong thing.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Web-service is not the problem , because I tried posting data with multiple attributes, and it's getting posted successfully.So there is no problem with the web-service. Yes regarding your second point , I also think, there is a problem with the modifying code.I have posted all the code.So the problem is, I don't know how to send $scope.choices with  $scope.product, because some of the fields will be binding to $scope.product, and attributes field will be binding to $scope.choices.So how can I Post this kind of data to web-service ?

Comment: So are you saying that you have the same keys and values in $scope.choices as $scope.product? In that case why don't you use two way data binding for $scope.choice in ur ng-models

Comment: @Vivz : My model contains data in following fashion : **productName,productDescription** ,second part is productAttributes ,**size , color** which is an array, i.e for same product I can have multiple **size , color**. So I am dynamically creating these fields using angular js.But I dont know topost this kind of data to web-service..

Comment: And what is there in $scope.choices? And with what data do u want to call ur API?

Comment: @Vivz : $scope.choices is holding dynamically created fields.Actually both $scope.product & $scope.choices are part of one schema. so for **productName,productDescripion** I want to use $scope.product, & for **size,color** I want to use $scope.choices.

Comment: I don't know whether I am doing it right. If there is some better solution for this kind of problem please suggest.

Comment: Where are you initialising ur $scope.choices and why do u want to ng-repeat over choices because choice contains all the instance present in $scope.product, so are you trying to implement an edit functionality by prepopulating the inputs with fields u get in $scope.choice?

Comment: No , I am inserting data as a new entry .

Comment: My model contains data in following fashion : productName,productDescription ,second part is productAttributes ,size , color which is an array, i.e for same product I can have multiple size , color. So I am dynamically creating these fields using angular js.But I dont know to post this kind of data to web-service.

Comment: Ok understood, so u want to send data to server in the form of an object that contains the above fields and size and color are coming from inputs but from where are u getting the other values like productName etc from for post?

Comment: for productName,prodcutDescription I am using $scope.product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly bind the choice of color and and size to `$scope.product` by structuring it the way you want. So initialise `productStock` key of `$scope.product` to an array by `$scope.product.productStock= [];`. That way your object will be created in the desired way because of two way data binding.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-12">
        <form ng-submit="addProducts()">
       <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="val in product.productStock">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <hr>
         <h3>Attributes</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.price" placeholder="Enter price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Color</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.color" placeholder="Enter color">
                            </div>
    </fieldset>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
                 </form>
              <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>  
        </div>  
</form><br/>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.product.productStock= [];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.product.productStock.length+1;
    $scope.product.productStock.push({price:'',color:''});
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.product.productStock.length-1;
    if(lastItem > 0){
    $scope.product.productStock.splice(lastItem);
    }
  };

$scope.addProducts = function () {
   console.log($scope.product)
        $http.post('/products/createProduct', $scope.product).then(function (res) {


        });
    }
```

You can initialize the object in the following way

```
  $scope.product={
       productName:YourProductValue,  
       productDescription:YourDescriptionValue,
       productStock:[]

  };
```

Comment: Getting this error :   "TypeError: Cannot set property 'productStock' of undefined
    at new <anonymous>"

Comment: Also  now I cannot add color, size multiple times .

Comment: Ii thought u had an object called $scope.product which had the name and description properties, if not initialise $scope.products ={};

Comment: How can I perform update operation on same schema ? I mean how can I again generate random number of fields with data to perform update operation. ?

Comment: Idk about backend but in view you will be using the same variable to prepopulate in your view

Comment: Okay  but , how my view will know how many attributes do my product has?

Comment: You have to call an api and fetch all the details for the view